# In read and write text file i have to print all the data in the text file but it print only the last line how to get all line write

Tags: java

Read and write the text.
In read and write text file i have to print all the data in the text file but it print only the last line how to get all line write.
Program:

```
public class fs
  {
    try
       {
            BufferReader in = new BufferReader(FileReader(C:/Users/madhan kumar/Desktop/read.txt));
        String s;
         String[] result=null;
        while((s=in.readLine())!=null)
        {

         result=s.split("\\|");
          result = String[4];
          String Name = result[0];
           String age = result[1];
           String Sex = result[2];
            String field = result[3];
              System.out.println("Name :"+Name+"Age                        :"+age+"Sex :"+Sex+"Field"+field);  
                       BufferedWriter bw =new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("out.txt");
        bw.write ("Name :"+Name+"Age                        :"+age+"Sex :"+Sex+"Field"+field);
     Bw.close ();
        }}
         catch(Exception e)
       {
       System.out.println(e);
      }
      }
      }


  My txt file
  malik|23|male|student
  nakul|30|male|student
  ram|27|male|worker
  mak|25|male|student
```

Comment: Please don't use tags that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Language tag spam, no clear question, poorly formatted code -- not a good start here. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works.

Comment: The first issue I see is that you have statements directly in the class body, and not in a method. The second issue I see is that you aren't closing the `try` block before calling `catch`. A style issue is that you aren't indenting properly, and you aren't using proper naming practices, where classes are TitleCase, and variables/methods are camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your main question is that you only see the last line because you create a new BufferedWriter every time you write out to the .txt, and when you do that it deletes text already on the .txt file. To solve this problem simply declare your BufferedWriter outside of the while loop:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class fs{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringTokenizer str;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/madhan kumar/Desktop/read.txt"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("out.txt"));
            String s;
            while((s=in.readLine())!=null){
                str = new StringTokenizer(s, "|");
                String name = str.nextToken();
                String age = str.nextToken();
                String sex = str.nextToken();
                String field = str.nextToken();
                System.out.println("Name:  "+name+"\tAge:  "+age+"\tSex:  "+sex+"\tField:  "+field);
                bw.write("Name:  "+name+"\tAge:  "+age+"\tSex:  "+sex+"\tField:  "+field);
            }
            bw.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I made a few small adjustments, largest being that I used StringTokenizer which does pretty much the same thing as your splitting method, but is a little more eloquent.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please clarify your question?